# Predicting Probabilities in Logistic Regression Model in Apache Spark MLib

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I am working on Apache Spark to build the LRM using the LogisticRegressionWithLBFGS() class provided by MLib. Once the Model is built, we can use the predict function provided which gives only the binary labels as the output. I also want the probabilities to be calculated for the same.

There is an implementation for the same found in

https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/mllib/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/mllib/classification/LogisticRegression.scala

```
override protected def predictPoint(
  dataMatrix: Vector,
  weightMatrix: Vector,
  intercept: Double) = {
require(dataMatrix.size == numFeatures)

// If dataMatrix and weightMatrix have the same dimension, it's binary logistic regression.
if (numClasses == 2) {
  val margin = dot(weightMatrix, dataMatrix) + intercept
  val score = 1.0 / (1.0 + math.exp(-margin))
  threshold match {
    case Some(t) => if (score > t) 1.0 else 0.0
    case None => score
  }
}
```

This method is not exposed, and also the probabilities are not available. Can I know how to use this function to get probabilities.
The dot method which is used in the above function is also not exposed, it is present in the BLAS Package but it is not public.

Comment: what do you mean by `exposed`? and what is your actual question?

Comment: Instead of getting the prediction I want predicted probabilities. Exposed means the method cannot be called using the model. The LRM Model gives only the predict() function but not predictPoint().

Comment: what is your spark version?

Comment: Have you seen `org.apache.spark.ml.classification.LogisticRegression` (note the "ml" package)? Might only work in a *Pipeline* though.

Comment: What do you mean by pipeline? @stholzm

Comment: *Pipelines* are an experimental high-level API for machine learning tasks: https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/ml-guide.html#pipeline

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Call `myModel.clearThreshold` to get the raw prediction instead of the 0/1 labels.

Mind this only works for Binary Logistic Regression (numClasses == 2).

Comment: Thanks a lot @selvinsource, the method you suggested is working as expected. As of now we are using this for Binary Classification, so this is perfect

Answer (score 3):

I encountered a similar problem in trying to obtain the raw predictions for a multiples problem. For me, the best solution was to create a method by borrowing and customizing from the [Spark MLlib Logistic Regression src](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/mllib/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/mllib/classification/LogisticRegression.scala). You can create a like so:

```
object ClassificationUtility {
  def predictPoint(dataMatrix: Vector, model: LogisticRegressionModel):
    (Double, Array[Double]) = {
    require(dataMatrix.size == model.numFeatures)
    val dataWithBiasSize: Int = model.weights.size / (model.numClasses - 1)
    val weightsArray: Array[Double] = model.weights match {
      case dv: DenseVector => dv.values
      case _ =>
        throw new IllegalArgumentException(
          s"weights only supports dense vector but got type ${model.weights.getClass}.")
    }
    var bestClass = 0
    var maxMargin = 0.0
    val withBias = dataMatrix.size + 1 == dataWithBiasSize
    val classProbabilities: Array[Double] = new Array[Double](model.numClasses)
    (0 until model.numClasses - 1).foreach { i =>
      var margin = 0.0
      dataMatrix.foreachActive { (index, value) =>
      if (value != 0.0) margin += value * weightsArray((i * dataWithBiasSize) + index)
      }
      // Intercept is required to be added into margin.
      if (withBias) {
        margin += weightsArray((i * dataWithBiasSize) + dataMatrix.size)
      }
      if (margin > maxMargin) {
        maxMargin = margin
        bestClass = i + 1
      }
      classProbabilities(i+1) = 1.0 / (1.0 + Math.exp(-(margin - maxMargin)))
    }
    return (bestClass.toDouble, classProbabilities)
  }
}
```

Note it is only slightly different from the original method, it just calculates the logistic as a function of the input features. It also defines some vals and vars that are originally private and included outside of this method. Ultimately, it indexes the scores in an Array and returns it along with the best answer. I call my method like so:

```
// Compute raw scores on the test set.
val predictionAndLabelsAndProbabilities = test
  .map { case LabeledPoint(label, features) =>
val (prediction, probabilities) = ClassificationUtility
  .predictPoint(features, model)
(prediction, label, probabilities)}
```

**However:**

It seems the Spark contributors are discouraging the use of `MLlib` in favor of `ML`. The ML logistic regression API currently does not support multiples classification. I am now using [OneVsRest](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/mllib/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/ml/classification/OneVsRest.scala) which acts as a wrapper for one vs all classification. I am working on a similar customization to get the raw scores.

Comment: Can you add a link to the (non-MLlib) ML library?

Comment: @user48956 Sure, here is the link to the OneVsRest documentation: http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/ml-classification-regression.html#one-vs-rest-classifier-aka-one-vs-all The cool thing is that you can interact with the models individually as is discussed in the SO thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36243455/spark-ml-save-onevsrestmodel

Comment: This is a meaty answer - deserves at *least* as much support as the accepted one. I am looking into the use of the `OneVsRest`

Answer (score 0):

I believe the call is `myModel.clearThreshold()`; i.e. `myModel.clearThreshold` without the parentheses fails. See the linear SVM example [here](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/mllib-linear-methods.html).