# Spark ML - Save OneVsRestModel

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-mllib, apache-spark-ml

I am in the middle of refactoring my code to take advantage of [DataFrames, Estimators, and Pipelines](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/ml-guide.html). I was originally using [MLlib Multiclass LogisticRegressionWithLBFGS](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/mllib-linear-methods.html#logistic-regression) on `RDD[LabeledPoint]`. I am enjoying learning and using the new API, but I am not sure how to save my new model and apply it on new data.

Currently, the ML implementation of `LogisticRegression` only supports binary classification. I am, instead using [OneVsRest](https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.5.2/ml-ensembles.html#one-vs-rest-aka-one-vs-all) like so:

```
val lr = new LogisticRegression().setFitIntercept(true)
val ovr = new OneVsRest()
ovr.setClassifier(lr)
val ovrModel = ovr.fit(training)
```

I would now like to save my `OneVsRestModel`, but this does not seem to be supported by the API. I have tried:

```
ovrModel.save("my-ovr") // Cannot resolve symbol save
ovrModel.models.foreach(_.save("model-" + _.uid)) // Cannot resolve symbol save
```

Is there a way to save this, so I can load it in a new application for making new predictions?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Spark 2.0.0**

`OneVsRestModel` implements `MLWritable` so it should be possible to save it directly. Method shown below can be still useful to save individual models separately.

**Spark < 2.0.0**

The problem here is that `models` returns an `Array` of `ClassificationModel[_, _]]` not an `Array` of `LogisticRegressionModel` (or `MLWritable`). To make it work you'll have to be specific about the types:

```
import org.apache.spark.ml.classification.LogisticRegressionModel

ovrModel.models.zipWithIndex.foreach { 
  case (model: LogisticRegressionModel, i: Int) => 
    model.save(s"model-${model.uid}-$i")
}
```

or to be more generic:

```
import org.apache.spark.ml.util.MLWritable

ovrModel.models.zipWithIndex.foreach { 
  case (model: MLWritable, i: Int) =>
    model.save(s"model-${model.uid}-$i")
}
```

Unfortunately as for now (Spark 1.6) `OneVsRestModel` doesn't implement `MLWritable` so it cannot be saved alone.

**Note**:

All models int the `OneVsRest` seem to use the same `uid` hence we need an explicit index. It will be also useful to identify the model later.

Comment: I wish I could +2 this. Not only is this exactly what I needed, it makes the job of calculating the raw probabilities a lot easier. I thought I was going to have to customize the src. Thanks!

Comment: @zero323 is there a pyspark version of your answer ? Trying to find a way to save pyspark.ml models

Comment: @AjinkyaKale In 1.6?

Comment: @zero323 yes, using 1.6.1

Comment: @AjinkyaKale There is not `OneVsRest` in PySpark 1.6, is there? At first glance it can be easily backported but it is a different issue than this one. If you decide to backport this will be pretty much the same code.

Comment: @zero323 - my question was not actually for `OneVsRest` .. it was generic for any model from pyspark.ml to persist / save. Specifically I am trying to save a `pyspark.ml.feature.PCA` model. Documentation does not mention model persistence for `pyspark.ml` as they do for `mllib`

Comment: Not directly. PCA model is not writable.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/117762/discussion-between-ajinkya-kale-and-zero323).

Comment: @ajkl Were you able to find any solution on how to save pyspark.ml models and use them on hadoop clusters?